# File path magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')" error on https://www.website.com/static/version1649742238/frontend/Mgs/supro/en_AU/mage/utils/misc.js

I am not sure where should I locate this file to edit.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is static generated file you can find this in magento_root/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/supro/en_AU/mage/utils/misc.js

But it's original file can be found within magento_root/app/code/Mgs/supro

Try using find command in app/code/Mgs folder like
`find -name "misc.js"`

Magento versioning is enabled you can disable for development purpose set
MagentoAdmin->Stores->Configration->System->Developer->Static View files to no